# why couldn't 'self' recognize?

Tags: ios, recursion, lldb

I am developing iOS Application.

I would like to use recursiveDescription at one Page which has UITableView on lldb.
I move above page,then i stop Application by pause button. And I got the following error.

```
(lldb) po [self.workview recursiveDescription]
error: use of undeclared identifier 'self'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [self.view recursiveDescription]
error: use of undeclared identifier 'self'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

self.workview is instance of UITableView.
why couldn't 'self' recognize?

Comment: Who knows what the context is when you hit pause. Set a breakpoint on the line where you want to enter the debugger

Comment: I see.I will try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> then i stop Application by pause button...why couldn't 'self' recognize?

If you stopped the app by clicking the pause button in Xcode, you have no way to control what code is executing when the app stops. Execution could stop pretty much anywhere, and if `self` is defined at all wherever you stop, there's a very solid chance that it won't be defined to be the object you want it to be.

Instead of using the pause button, set a breakpoint in the source code for the class you want to debug.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I was able to do what i expected.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Caleb's answer, you can get any object's memory address while on a breakpoint and send message to that object after pausing app with following:

```
po self
```

Its output will be something like this:

```
<MYViewController: 0x7ffa63871800>
```

And then pause app with pause button and type this on console:

```
po [((MYViewController*)0x7ffa63871800).workview recursiveDescription]
```

Comment: I see.It is intersting to debug by lldb.Tnank you.